# run .swf files in electron project in windows os

Tags: windows, flash, electron

i have this code for convert website to exe file using electon js but i have problem
inside the website there are .swf files and i search alot about how i can run .swf files but it's not work 
i was traing by plugin it's name "Pepper Flash Plugin"
this is the url for this plugin

https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/using-pepper-flash-plugin/

and i was searsh about "pepflashplayer.dll"

and put it on the root on prject directory and also not work

any help please

```
file:main.js

'use strict';

const electron = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const app = electron.app;  // Module to control application life.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;  // Module to create native browser window.



// Specify flash path, supposing it is placed in the same directory with main.js.
let pluginName
switch (process.platform) {
  case 'win32':
    pluginName = 'pepflashplayer.dll'
    break
  case 'darwin':
    pluginName = 'PepperFlashPlayer.plugin'
    break
  case 'linux':
    pluginName = 'libpepflashplayer.so'
    break
}
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ppapi-flash-path', path.join(__dirname, pluginName))

var mainWindow = null;

app.on('ready', function() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1100, height: 900, webPreferences: {
      plugins: true
    }});

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/cd/cd/START.html');
});
```

Comment: This code seems quite right to me. Do you use the `plugins` attribute on the `webview` tag in `START.html` that should display the `.swf`?

Comment: the code above work correctly and the problem was by "pepflashplayer.dll"
i download this file from the internet for that it was not work and flash file not work too
and the answer is ..go to this URL on chrome browser "chrome://plugins/"
and you will see your plugins that installed on your browser and between them you will found flash player that name "pepflashplayer.dll" just copy this file to your project and it's will work

Comment: i don't use webview attribute on the iframe that view the .swf file and it's work on development mode and in product mode

Answer (score 1):

```
case 'win32':
  pluginName = 'pepflashplayer.dll'
```

You simply need to put in the directory to where your dll file is located

Currently (June 2017) it is stored at:
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\PepperFlash\26.0.0.126

```
case 'win32':
  pluginName = 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\PepperFlash\26.0.0.126\pepflashplayer.dll'
```

**OR**

copy the dll to your app's directory and point it to there

```
case 'win32':
  pluginName = './pepflashplayer.dll'
```