# Can I bundle Pepper Flash in an Electron.js app to run Flash in 2021+?

Tags: flash, electron

So, I have followed https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-pepper-flash-plugin and have successfully ran our Flash app inside Electron with an embedded Chrome 83 version.

I have even tested setting the computer clock ahead into 2022 and confirmed it still runs Flash and avoids the Flash time bomb (Jan 12, 2021 is the Flash time bomb date according to my testing) that is built into the regular browser Flash plugins.

However, am I allowed to distribute the Electron Mac & Windows binaries to our customers? Any insight would be much appreciated!

**Update 12/18/2020**:
Any recent build of Adobe Flash is going to have a Jan 12, 2021 time bomb. If you want to run Flash in 2021+, you have to use the Harman Flash plugins and embed in an Electron app: https://services.harman.com/partners/adobe

Harman can also provide you an Electron app with the plugins embedded.

Comment: Did you find any solutions to this question?

Comment: Can you check maybe this answer applies to you too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65254243/does-the-flash-executable-itself-stop-flash-from-working-january-12-2021

Answer (score 2):

In email conversations directly with Adobe staff, I have confirmed you need to have a Flash licensing contract to legally distribute the Flash plugins in an Electron app. I believe it's always been this way and will continue to be.

However, Adobe is no longer the company to work with for licensing. Adobe has endorsed Harman as the Flash partner/maintainer going forward into the future. See https://services.harman.com/partners/adobe

If you connect with Harman, they can sell you a license that will allow you to distribute the Flash plugins in an Electron app ongoing into the future. They can also provide you a packaged browser (their own Electron app) that points to your Flash URL.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I read that Flash Licensing Contract is only required when we distribute that application, but if we use the application internally in our organization, then the we don't need to worry of the licensing part?

Comment: I'm not sure on that. I would connect with Harman and ask. I do know the FireFox Extended Support version will be running Flash past Dec 2020... last I heard was until August 2021, but that could have changed. It would however need to be configured via an "enterprise policy file" to whitelist Flash for your domain.

I've also heard some things about Microsoft Edge running Flash post 2020 for enterprises. You could check into that as well.

Comment: Isn't possible that the chromium browser embedded in the Electorn App will block flash content from running as of 1 of January? Maybe it will receive an updated list of plugins to block in that date.

Thanks

Comment: @frankieta I see no evidence of that. Harman, the official Adobe Flash maintainer going forward, distributes an Electron app with their Flash plugins embedded. I would say however that Electron versions released in 2021 will most likely not have Flash support so you have to use an Electron version released before 2021.

Comment: Harman hasn't replied back to me and I've contacted them 3 times already. Waited over a week. This solution doesn't work.